# Mockito upgrade causes null pointer problems

Tags: java, mockito

We upgraded from mockito-all-1.8.5.jar to mockito-all-1.9.0.jar and now see null pointers when using annotations for the classes being mocked.  Here is an example:

```java
  @Mock
  private static IAccountManager accountManager;
  @Mock
  private static IBusinessUnitManager businessUnitManager;
  private static Gson parser;

  @InjectMocks
  private static DownloadController downloadController;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    parser = new Gson();

    downloadController = new DownloadController(accountManager,
        businessUnitManager, parser);
  }

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Mockito.reset(accountManager, businessUnitManager);
  }
```

As soon as accountManager is referenced in the download controller, it throws a npe.  This worked in 1.8.5.

Comment: Is it because your fields are static?

Comment: Yes, it turns out I had to remove @InjectMocks since not all of the parameters could be injected and remove static from DownloadController.  If you would like to move your comment to an answer I'll select it.

Comment: ahh, long day.  By injected I meant mocked...lol

Comment: Added the answer now. I didn't add it as answer before as it was a bit of a random guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the injected mocks failed is because they are static fields. Static fields are generally reserved for fields that remain constant and do not change from test to test, and can sometimes be expensive to instantiate. This is the reverse for instance fields, where a new instance of the test class is created for each test method (thus having it's instance fields 'reset'). It would seem Mockito adheres to this philosophy and does not attempt to instantiate static fields.

The fix is either to make your fields non-static, or if you need them to be static then set them up in the `BeforeClass` method.

Answer (score 4):

You could look at http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=327 on the Mockito issues register.  If this is the issue you're experiencing, then it has been fixed already and will be in release 1.9.1 of Mockito.  If you think your issue is different from this one, please go to http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues and raise it, so that it can be fixed.